# Handling Express Router Middlewares

Tags: node.js, express

So on router level file, I need to protect almost all routes with at least one middleware, except for one route. So far I tried something like this:

```
// comments.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
const m = require('../middlewares');

// /api/:newsId/comments - preappended route

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(req.path == '/' && req.method == 'GET') return next(); // doesn't work, even with next('route')
    if(m.isLoggedIn) { // this doesn't work either
        next();
    }
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // returns comments for :newsId, only this route doesn't need middlewares
})

// all below routes needs at least m.isLoggedIn
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // creates a new comment
})

// ...
// bunch of other routes which needs middleware m.isLoggedIn and maybe some others

module.exports = router;
```

I know I can append middlewares on each route, but I am looking for better solution to use in ***router.use()***.

Comment: Show the code of `../middlewares`

Comment: That is set upped how it needs to be, and it works on all other routes, but here it is anyway: **isLoggedIn: (req, res, next) => passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })(req, res, next)**. Middlewares are not problem, it's just how to protect routes with them in comments.js

Comment: `req.path` will be `/api/:newsId/comments`. Use Regex to validate all this kind of path. In second condition, check second route with Regex and `return m.isLoggedIn(req, res, next)`

Comment: I can't put **return** in condition..

Comment: sorry, just `m.isLoggedIn(req, res, next)`

Comment: Sorry, out of my head, I don't think that will work? Because that function doesn't return true or false, it just calls *next()* callback...

Comment: yes, when `isLoggedIn` will call `next`, express will invoke next handler.